# How to import a lot of Wordpress posts without crashing your browser?

Tags: wordpress, import, export, posts

I have a lot of custom posts I need to rescue from one wordpress site to another.

I've exported them using the default Wordpress Post exporter by going to **Tools -> Export**.

Then I've imported them using the default Wordpress Post importer by going to **Tools -> Import -> Wordpress**.

Now here's the problem, the import runs absolutely fine, as far as I can tell, but every time it imports a post, it creates a bunch of HTML elements telling me to update the author of each post, and it crashes Chrome.

Yes, that bad. I don't even have the time to delete those elements, Chrome simply gives up.

Is there any other way to export/import a huge amount of *custom* posts like that?

Comment: Are you importing these posts into a fresh WordPress setup?

Comment: export those posts categorywise. That way your import files will be less heavy. Yes, it takes memory while uploading. And while uploading you can select owner drom dropdown I think, no need to select for each post separately.

Comment: @Alice, how can I do that?

Comment: @cabrerahector I'm actually importing them into a newer version of the same site, basically the posts were deleted by accident and the older version has them, so I'm using it as a last resort backup.

Comment: Why not import the database (and `uploads` folder) instead? Unless you have existing content there, in which case what Alice suggests may be the best approach here.

Comment: Have you tried using another browser to see if it behaves the same way? Try Firefox or Edge

Comment: I tried in Edge and it didn't automatically crash though it still slowed down to a crawl, but it was enough to delete the `<ol>` parent element and finally get the import to finalize, I will explain more in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably hitting the PHP timeout and memory limits on the host.

Increase `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` in php.ini and raise memory, too.

If you don't have access to the php.ini file, try these in .htaccess which might override php.ini, depending on the host server config. But they may also throw a 500 error becuase of web host settings, so be ready to revert .htaccess

```
max_execution_time = 120
max_input_time = 120
memory_limit = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

You can also try raising PHP memory in wp-config.php with this line near the top of the file:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

Comment: Sorry, no, it's crashing my browser, not my server.

Comment: @undefined You should at least try this solution. I thought the same thing. It's possible that if you hit a memory limit (or a timeout) on the server, the lack of a proper response might be causing the client to crash

Comment: Interesting, however that was not the case, I was finally able to delete the elements it was generating on time (an ordered list) and the process finalized successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was for some reason the import process wanted to make me manually select a user for each post, which generated the gazillion elements and crashed the browser.

In Chrome it automatically crashed, didn't even let me access the inspector panel. On Edge, I managed to actually open the inspector and delete the parent element, an ordered list (`<ol>`).

Then I let the process finalize (just waiting until something happened, obviously I wasn't able to see any progress) and finally a button appeared, and I could finalize the import.

Meh, pretty stupid solution to a pretty stupid problem, but hey it works. Maybe it'll save someone else.